# Do android developers commonly use 3rd-party UI/networking libraries like Three20 on iPhone?

Tags: android, three20

I've done plenty of iPhone work, never anything with Android. On iPhone, it was a few months in before I discovered the Three20 library (which is awesome) and began moving my code over. I don't want to make the same mistakes moving to Android, so my question:

Do android developers commonly use 3rd-party UI/networking libraries like Three20 on iPhone, or do they take the ones out of the box? I realize that there is an effort to port Three20 to Android, but that's not my goal per se. I just want to know if the out-of-the-box UI/networking/navigation libs you get with android are considered sufficient for most android apps.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say no, it's not popular, and AFAIK there are no such GUI templates. Bot in other words yes, since a lot of stuff is open-source, we look-up things how are done by others, and re-use them.

Comment: Please tell me you're kidding. Three20 is a complete abomination. It is a perfect example of the wrong way to write Cocoa code, and it is the complete opposite of modular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had a problem using the ones out of the box.

Perhaps, as Pentium10 mentioned on a comment, I read some open-source code and get some ideas but the final answer to your question is no.

Comment: droid-fu is actually a library similar to Three20 insofar as it provides off the shelf components for common droid tasks