# Is there any three20 framework for android?

Tags: android

Is there any three20 framework (Or something like it) for android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, but you can get some inspiration in many other open projects in GitHub and/or code.google.com. Please see some links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there/4322898#4322898).

Comment: broken link... try this instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248876/are-there-libraries-similar-to-the-three20-project-for-android